# Find Group Policy object to allow ms-appinstaller protocol

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We're running a proof of concept of an application, the preferred deployment method is web install:

1. The user goes to the locally hosted app server
2. If the user is in the AD Group for the application a "launch" link is provided.
3. The user clicks "launch" and the app downloads and runs.

For some users we get the error message:

```
Cannot open app package
Reason: the ms-appinstaller protocol has been disabled by policy. Contact your administrator of assistance.
```

I've managed to determine that the difference between the users that can launch and the ones that can't is that the users that can are in another, unrelated, application group.

<strike>This gives us a workaround, but we'd rather not give people access to an application they don't need, just so they can access the right one.</strike>

Is there a simple (powershell, preferably) way to find all the GPOs that the unrelated application group is linked to? Or, if it's easier, can I just find the GPO based on the ms-appinstaller protocol?

Having tested the workaround, it seems that it's nothing to do with the AD group, but it's dependent on the computer they are using.

It would be good to know what the configuration option is. All these laptops are meant to be running an SOE, but the more recent ones work, so there might be some kind of change.